# Validating double field in struts 2

Tags: validation, struts2

I have a field "length" in one of my struts 2 form. The data-type of "length" is "double". I have applied the "double" validation in XML file. But when I key-in alphabets in the "length" text field, it shows the error message as

```
Invalid field value for field "length"
```

I don't want this message to be shown like this. This message is generated by struts 2 itself and not entered by me. I guess, this message comes as the conversion of data fails. I also applied the "conversion" validator, but the above error message is still showing up. Please suggest the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck. This text is customizable.

The text is defined in xwork-messages.properties in the xwork jar. You can override it by adding the following to your global i18n resource bundle:

```
xwork.default.invalid.fieldvalue=Invalid field value for field "{0}".
```

As you guessed, this error message occurs for all type conversion failures. The `XWorkConverter` class has some useful javadoc about this:

> Any error that occurs during type conversion may or may not wish to be reported. For example, reporting that the input "abc" could not be converted to a number might be important. On the other hand, reporting that an empty string, "", cannot be converted to a number might not be important - especially in a web environment where it is hard to distinguish between a user not entering a value vs. entering a blank value.
>
> By default, all conversion errors are reported using the generic i18n key **xwork.default.invalid.fieldvalue**, which you can override (the default text is *Invalid field value for field "xxx"*, where xxx is the field name) in your global i18n resource bundle.
>
> However, sometimes you may wish to override this message on a per-field basis. You can do this by adding an i18n key associated with just your action (Action.properties) using the pattern **invalid.fieldvalue.xxx**, where xxx is the field name.
>
> It is important to know that none of these errors are actually reported directly. Rather, they are added to a map called *conversionErrors* in the ActionContext. There are several ways this map can then be accessed and the errors can be reported accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer. It solved my problem and also added some knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<field name="percentage">
    <field-validator type="double">
        <param name="minExclusiveExpression">${minExclusiveValue}</param>
        <param name="maxExclusiveExpression">${maxExclusiveValue}</param>
        <message>Percentage needs to be between ${minExclusive} and ${maxExclusive} (exclusive)</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```