# remove conversion validation message in struts 2 or make it general

Tags: struts2, validation

In my struts2 application I have field named carrierNo that accepts integer, when i put string in it gives me this validation error message:

```
    *Invalid field value for field "carrierNo".*
```

i can customize this error message in the properties file like this

```
    invalid.fieldvalue.carrierNo=this field does not accept characters
```

but i don't want to write a customized message for every non String field in my web application, i want to make it general, i tried the following but it did not work

```
  invalid.fieldvalue.%{getText(fieldName)}=this field does not accept characters
```

if there is no way to make general, please help me disable this message at all.
then i will use converstion field validator with single message that i define in the properties file.

so my request is to help me make this invalid.fieldvalue.carrierNo general something like this form invalid.fieldvalue.%{getText(fieldName)}

or disable the display of this error message *Invalid field value for field "carrierNo".*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own implementation of `ConversionErrorInterceptor` which finds out the class of failed field and gets your custom message.

**Edit:** 
See source code for `ConversionErrorInterceptor`. For example you could do something like this in your custom interceptor inside `intercept` method

```
// get field by name from action
Field f = invocation.getAction().getClass().getDeclaredField(propertyName);
// get type of field
Class clz = f.getType();

String message = LocalizedTextUtil.findDefaultText(XWorkMessages.DEFAULT_INVALID_FIELDVALUE + "." + clz,
                    invocationContext.getLocale());
```

And in your messages.properties file put `xwork.default.invalid.fieldvalue.int`, `xwork.default.invalid.fieldvalue.float`, etc.

Comment: can you give me a brief example please.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way to remove conversion messages is to remove the ["conversionError" interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/conversion-error-interceptor.html) from your default stack. One problem with removing it, however, is that IIRC it's also responsible for putting the original (non-converted) value back into fields instead of having them replaced by the value of the failed conversion. This can lead to an unpleasant user experience, IMO.

Making a "... does not accept characters" conversion error message doesn't feel right: conversion errors encompass the entire application, and characters may not be the reason for a conversion error.

Comment: so what is the solution, i don't want to make a message for every non String field in my applications there will be thousands. i want something general.
for example a message for integers and one for date.
I want to minimize the number of error message.

if i disable the interceptor, will i be able to catch the conversion error using the Conversion field validator?

Comment: You should better check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634930/validating-double-field-in-struts-2)

Comment: @anyulled That answers a different question, namely, how do I *customize* the conversion error message. I also disagree with the accepted answer, in that customized conversion errors based solely on class may not address specific business requirements.