# Is it possible to configure a custom error message per converter?

Tags: java, struts2

Is it possible to configure a custom error message per converter?

For example I have this in my **xwork-conversion.properties**:

```
java.util.Date=mx.com.afirme.midas2.converter.DateConverter
```

Whenever a Date conversion fails in any action I'd like to show a message like this:

> Incorrect format, expected mm/dd/yyyy

I don't want to define a custom message per property as mentioned in the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html):

> However, sometimes you may wish to override this message on a
>   per-field basis. You can do this by adding an i18n key associated with
>   just your action (Action.properties) using the pattern
>   invalid.fieldvalue.xxx, where xxx is the field name.

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12347173/1700321.